# Finding Binet form in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a linear recurrence* and I want to find its closed-form 'Binet' representation.  Is there a good way to do this in Mathematica?

It seems like a very basic request, and there are certainly many natural ways to ask Mathematica to do it for me.  But so far everything I've tried has failed: it churns until its memory use is so high the operating system is obliged to close it, or it gives warnings that it does not know how to simplify simple expressions†, or the like.  I could understand this if the question was hard, but it's not—factor the characteristic equation, find the roots, and solve a linear system. The most recent time I tried this (and had the program crash) was on a degree-9 example, and I just don't think a 9-by-9 linear system should be that hard to solve.

Surely I'm not the only one who need to do this from time to time!  What is the right way to do this?

I lost my session so I don't have the exact code I tried.  One solution created a List with the recurrence and its initial points and used RSolve.  Another found and factored the characteristic equation and took appropriate roots to the n-th power multiplied by polynomials of degree corresponding to the multiplicity with coefficients generated from C[i].  I also tried Solve and Reduce in various ways.

*** Or a rational generating function. Actually I'll start from a `List` of numbers which are described by a recurrence of less than half its length, and `FindLinearRecurrence` or `FindGeneratingFunction` can do the not-too-difficult conversion.

† For example, when I asked it to solve one recurrence it choked on sin^2 (3pi/14) + cos^2(3pi/14) in the course of the calculation, saying that ran out of precision.  You'd think it could symbolically simplify something like that, but no.

Comment: Do you mean this?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetForms.html

If so, there isn't going to be a function to do it for you, but it doesn't look like too bad a of a program to write.

Comment: @Searke: Yes.  Any linear recurrence has a formula in the form `a[n_] := Sum[polynomial[[i]][n] * base[[i]]^n, {i, 1, k}]` for some Lists polynomial and base of length k.  I'd like to find these lists.  The four programs I wrote all failed to give an answer: the programs were correct but Mathematica was unable to solve the equations for reasons I outlined above. I'm looking for a way around Mathemastica's limitations.

Comment: Push come to shove I can write a program from the ground-up to do this, not using Mathematica's symbolic capabilities, but in that case I won't be using Mathematica, either -- why pay the performance cost if you can't use any of the advanced features?

Comment: "It seems like a very basic request". Hmmm, given that I'd never heard of a Binet representation before it might not be that basic (but then, it might just be me). The two Binet forms on the Mathworld lemma referenced above seem to be easily solved by RSolve though seemingly giving the correct result. BTW what's in your list polynomial?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: It depends on the recurrence, of course.  For the Fibonacci numbers it would be `{Sqrt[1/5]&, Sqrt[1/5]&}` I think, with base as `{GoldenRatio, 1/GoldenRatio}`.  (The way I wrote my comment I think I need to store the polynomials as lambda expressions, is there a better way?)  In that example both polynomials are constant; in others they may not be.

Comment: As for being basic (or not), I think that linear recurrences are very standard and they have just three common representations: recurrence, generating function, and exponential/Binet.  The last one provides information on the asymptotic behavior and makes it very easy to approximate the values, so that's why I think of it as basic.  That and the fact that it isn't that difficult to calculate, which is why I can't figure out why Mathematica can't handle it.

Comment: A simple example input and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: I gave desired output above in my Fibonacci example.  The input could be {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8} (or a longer list of Fibonacci numbers) or it could be more explicit, say a list {1, 1} of recurrence coefficients (corresponding to a[n] == 1*a[n-1] + 1*a[n-2]) and a list {0, 1} of initial values (which, as before, could be a longer list of Fibonacci numbers if desired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but you could do something like

```
Binet[ker_List, init_List] := 
 Module[{charp, roots, polynomials, coeffs, base, p}, 
  roots = Tally[
    N@Eigenvalues[
      PadLeft[Append[IdentityMatrix[Length[ker] - 1], Reverse[ker]]]]];
  coeffs = Table[p[i, j], {i, Length[roots]}, {j, roots[[i, 2]]}];
  polynomials = 
   Table[(Evaluate[i.#^Range[0, Length[i] - 1]]) &, {i, coeffs}];
  base = roots[[All, 1]];
  {polynomials /. 
    Solve[Table[
       Through[polynomials[n]].base^n == init[[n + 1]], {n, 0, 
        Length[init] - 1}], Flatten[coeffs]][[1]], base}]
```

Then for a linear recurrence `kernel` and initial values `init`, `Binet[kernel, init]` returns two lists. The first one contains the polynomials and the second the roots of the characteristic polynomial. The `n`-th entry in the recurrence table is then equal to `a[kernel, init][n]` with

```
a[kernel_, init_] := Evaluate@Module[{p, b}, 
   {p, b} = Binet[kernel, init];
   Through[p[#]].b^#] &
```

So for example for the Fibonacci sequence you would get

```
kernel = {1, 1};
init = {1, 1};
{p, b} = Binet[kernel, init]

(* ==> {{0.723607 &, 0.276393 &}, {1.61803, -0.618034}} *)

With[{sol = a[{1, 1}, {1, 1}]}, 
  Table[Chop@sol[n], {n, 0, 10}]];

(* ==> {1., 1., 2., 3., 5., 8., 13., 21., 34., 55., 89.} *)
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks.  Is it possible for Mathematica to give exact solutions here with `Root` objects (or their simplified equivalents when they exist)?

Comment: @Charles Try removing the N@ before Eigenvalues and see if that works in terms of speed and correctness. (I think it will be correct, not sure about speed or size of results though.) I also suspect one could get this form from RSolve results, but I am not sufficiently clear on what a Binet form is to be certain.

Comment: OK, I removed `N@` and ran `f=Binet[{2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 13, 16}]`. (This is the example that caused the crash earlier.) The `f[[1]][[i]]` are, of course, functions so I evaluated them to convert them into numbers that could be simplified. `f[[1]][[1]][]`, `f[[1]][[2]][]`, etc. worked, but `f[[1]][[5]][]` did not for some reason: it gave a `Function::slotn` error instead. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Sidenote: the function so far has a `LeafCount` of 508300, which is a bit high. It took me a while but my hand-simplified version (not in Mathematica, but not using any special commands) is 43 _characters_ long; its Mathematica equivalent is a bit longer with 63 characters and a LeafCount of 29.  So I feel like I have a way to go still before I can use a Mathematica function to take over this tedious task.

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of Binet form, but addressing your concern regarding simplification:

```
expr = Sin[3 pi/14]^2 + Cos[3 pi/14]^2;

Simplify[expr]
```

```
1
```

Comment: Yes, if I feed it this directly it can simplify it.  But when it comes across it in the course of the calculation it not only will not simplify it but ends the computation entirely as a result.

Comment: @Charles I am sorry this was not helpful.  Could you give me a short code sample where *Mathematica* chokes on this?  Was the expression generated in the course of evaluation, or given explicitly (in which case it is plausible to Simplify first)?

Comment: Generated in the course of evaluation.  I had never typed `Sin` at all, it was generated by Mathematica and Mathematica decided it could not complete the calculation without it.  Had it finished the calculation and left it unsimplified I could have used `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, or even `/.` to get rid of it, but it didn't.

Comment: I will give a +1 for effort, though. :)

Comment: I lost the exact expression when Mathematica crashed but I'll try to find another that gives the same sort of message.